# read inserted data from excel spreadsheet while program execution POI, JAVA

Tags: java, excel, user-interface, apache-poi

I am creating an application that reads excel file into the programs and manipulates them. Before now, everything worked fine. But when I stareted implementing the GUI for my application it does not work anymore.

here is the code:

when the program launches it creates a gui with buttons and opens 2 new spreadsheets. I enter data in those spreadsheets and then press the button that calls crossReferenceButtonListener, however it fails to get the data out. error message below

```
public GUI () throws Exception{
    this.setTitle("NYWM Cross Reference Application");
    this.setSize(400,100);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    buttonHolder = new Panel (new BorderLayout());
    this.add(buttonHolder);

    crossReference = new Button ("CrossReference");
    generateHPD = new Button ("Generate HPD");

    buttonHolder.add(crossReference, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    buttonHolder.add(generateHPD, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    crossReference.addActionListener(new crossReferenceButtonListener());
    generateHPD.addActionListener(new generateHPDButtonListener());

    createExcelSheet (log,"C:/Log.xlsx", "Log");
    createExcelSheet(sheet,"C:/Spreadsheet.xlsx", "Spreadsheet");


}

private void createExcelSheet (XSSFWorkbook wb, String path, String fileName) throws Exception{
        try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (path);
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook ();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(fileName);
        wb.write(out);

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "rundll32 url.dll, FileProtocolHandler " + path);


        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private class crossReferenceButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
            try {


                ref = new CrossReference (log.getSheet("Log"), sheet.getSheet("Spreadsheet"));
                ref.CrossReference();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cross Reference was successful!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

error message: to be more specific, it fails at this line

```
 ref = new CrossReference (log.getSheet("Log"), sheet.getSheet("Spreadsheet"));
```

error:

```
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at nywm_crossReferenceApplication.GUI$crossReferenceButtonListener.actionPerformed(GUI.java:70)
    at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which line in your code is the line 70 from the exception?

Comment: made it more clear. see    error message: to be more specific, it fails at this line

Comment: Your error, the `NullPointerException`, sure seems to point to either `log` or `sheet` being null - have you checked that??

Comment: Where are your `log` and `sheet` variables in `crossReferenceButtonListener` coming from?

Comment: editted egain, see code. workbooks are fields and they r being set by constructor calling a method createExcelSheet

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
public GUI () throws Exception{
  this.setTitle("NYWM Cross Reference Application");
  this.setSize(400,100);
  this.setVisible(true);
  this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  buttonHolder = new Panel (new BorderLayout());
  this.add(buttonHolder);

  crossReference = new Button ("CrossReference");
  generateHPD = new Button ("Generate HPD");

  buttonHolder.add(crossReference, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  buttonHolder.add(generateHPD, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  // NOTE the order below has been flipped!!!!
  createExcelSheet (log,"C:/Log.xlsx", "Log");
  createExcelSheet(sheet,"C:/Spreadsheet.xlsx", "Spreadsheet");

  crossReference.addActionListener(new crossReferenceButtonListener());
  generateHPD.addActionListener(new generateHPDButtonListener());
}
```

In your original code, you create the button and then add the action listener:

```
crossReference.addActionListener(new crossReferenceButtonListener());
```

However, it's only after adding the `crossReferenceButtonListener` that you call `createExcelSheet`, which is where the `Workbook`s are actually being instantiated.  And that `crossReferenceButtonListener` wanted to use fields on the `Workbook`s, but they were null, thus your `NullPointerException`.

By calling the `createExcelSheet` methods before you add that `crossReferenceButtonListener`, you will ensure that both `log` and `sheet` have been created by the time the `crossReferenceButtonListener` tries to use 'em.

Comment: this helped but did not solve the problem. or I would say just solved it partially. Thanx

Comment: However there is another problem a much deeper one. When the 2 workbooks open on my desktop they are new and empty. I enter data and click 'save' but the data dont seem to be saved. because now when I run int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum(); it throws an exception

Answer (score 1):

Java has no call-by-reference semantic. You are passing the two variables `log` and `sheet` to the method `createExcelSheet` obviously expecting them to be initialized within that method but that won’t work. They are still `null` after the method calls.

```
createExcelSheet (log,"C:/Log.xlsx", "Log");
createExcelSheet(sheet,"C:/Spreadsheet.xlsx", "Spreadsheet");
```

You have to rewrite that method to return the created `XSSFWorkbook` and change the calls to

```
log = createExcelSheet ("C:/Log.xlsx", "Log");
sheet = createExcelSheet("C:/Spreadsheet.xlsx", "Spreadsheet");
```

Comment: ...OR those variables can be members of the containing class and it will just work, as long as `createExcelSheet` is called before `rossReference.addActionListener(new crossReferenceButtonListener());`, per my answer.

Comment: These variables are already members of the containing class. This is not shown in the posted code but it can be deduced from the fact that they are not declared as local variables in the method. The problem is that they are never initialized and the factory method cannot initialize them as it is used two times for different variables. All attempts to tell that method which instance variable to initialize are far more complex than simply letting it return the created object and let the caller initialize the desired variable.